# Nextflow - No such variable: prefix

Tags: nextflow

I tried to run my nextflow script and the first two precess worded fine, but the third process Conbinevcf reported an error, showing that the variable prefix was not found.

```
process Annovar_genebased {

publishDir "${params.output}/annovar", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path 'snp_anatation' from anatation1.flatMap()
    val humandb
    val refgene

    output:
    path "*.exonic_variant_function" into end

   """
   prefix=\$(basename \$(readlink snp_anatation) .avinput)

   perl $refgene -geneanno -dbtype refGene -out \${prefix}.anatation -buildver hg19 $snp_anatation $humandb -hgvs

   rm *.log
   rm *.variant_function
   """
}


process Annovar {

publishDir "${params.output}/annovar", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path 'snp_anatation' from anatation2.flatMap()
    val annovar_table
    val humandb

    output:
    path "*.csv" into end1

   """
   prefix=\$(basename \$(readlink snp_anatation) .avinput)

   perl $annovar_table $snp_anatation $humandb -buildver hg19 -out \${prefix}.anatation -remove -protocol refGene,cytoBand,exac03,clinvar_20200316,gnomad211_exome -operation g,r,f,f,f -nastring . -csvout  -polish
   """
}
```

I got stuck on this process

```
process Combinevcf {

publishDir "${params.output}/combinevcf", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path 'genebased' from end.flatMap()
    path 'allbased' from end1.flatMap()

    output:
    path "*_3.csv" into end3

    """
    prefix=\$(basename \$(readlink genebased) .exonic_variant_function)
    prefix1=\$(basename \$(readlink allbased) .csv)

    cat ${prefix}.exonic_variant_function | tr -s ‘[:blank:]’ ‘,’ | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="," }{ print \$3,\$13,\$22}' | awk ' BEGIN { OFS=", "; print "refGene", "refGene", "refGene", "refGene", "refGene", "Zogysity","chr", "filter" } { print \$0, "" } ' > ${prefix}_1.csv

    awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="," }{ print \$1,\$2,\$3,\$4,\$5,\$6,\$7,\$8,\$9,\$10,\$15,\$21,\$24,\$25}' ${prefix1}.csv > ${prefix1}_2.csv

    paste ${prefix}_1.csv ${prefix1}_2.csv > ${prefix}_3.csv
    """
}
```

I am not sure what went wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your `${prefix}` with backslashes to tell nextflow that the variable `prefix` is in the script block scope, and not in the nextflow scope.

See https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#script for more info:

> Since Nextflow uses the same Bash syntax for variable substitutions in strings, you must manage them carefully depending on whether you want to evaluate a Nextflow variable or a Bash variable